# Using IN1/ IN2 pins for PWM instead of ENA in L298N

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32, pwm, l298n

So basically i tried providing PWM directly to the IN1/IN2 Of L298n motor driver instead of using ENA pin i got more or less the same result
Im using ESP32 with 30000Hz freq for my PWM
My question is if both ways it can be used why aren't people using this method? Or am i missing something?
I would love to know the reason if someone has any idea about it.

Comment: "why aren't people using this method?" It's not true, it's a widley used method.

Answer (score 0):

When using only IN1/2 to control **speed** and **direction**, you must apply PWM to IN1 for one direction and to IN2 for the other direction, while the other pin will be connected to ground. This method is easy to implement with a MCU but uses two PWM channels.
I think the EN pin is used for applications without MCUs or where there is only one PWM channel. In these situations, pins IN1/2 are used for STOP/CW/CCW selection and EN for speed from a single PWM source.